# Google Cloud Vision - How to Send Request Properties with Node.js

Tags: node.js, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I'm using Google Cloud Vision to detect text on an image. This works about 80% of the time. The other 20%, I get this error:

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request must specify image and features.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (C:\Users\emily\workspace\bot\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\emily\workspace\bot\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:180:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\emily\workspace\bot\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:336:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\emily\workspace\bot\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:299:181)
    at C:\Users\emily\workspace\bot\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:160:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
  code: 3,
  details: 'Request must specify image and features.',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
```

When I googled this issue, it seems I need to send specific headers with my request to resolve this, basically like as specified here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#specify_the_language_optional

However, I have no idea how to send these request parameters with the Node.js code I'm using and I can't find any examples anywhere. Can someone please help me figure out how to use this? My current code is this:

```
                // Performs text detection on the image file using GCV
                (async () => {
                    await Jimp.read(attachment.url).then(image => {
                        return image
                            .invert()
                            .contrast(0.5)
                            .brightness(-0.25)
                            .write('temp.png');
                    });

                    const [result] = await googleapis.textDetection('temp.png');
                    const fullImageResults = result.textAnnotations;
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is a separate npm module for cloud vision, https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision. Please refer to this page and you can use this library for making requests to vision api. 
Here is some sample code for image text detection, https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision/blob/main/samples/textDetection.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Node.js with Vision API you can refer to this [sample quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#detect_text_in_a_remote_image) code for using Node.js Client Library in Vision API for TEXT_DETECTION.

For the error that you are facing, you can refer to the below code to add request parameters:

**index.js :**

```
async function quickstart() {
   const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
    const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
    const request = {
     "requests": [
       {
         "image": {
           "source": {
             "imageUri": "gs://bucket1/download.png"
           }
         },
         "features": [
           {
             "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
           }
         ],
         "imageContext": {
           "languageHints": ["en"]
         }
       }
     ]
   };
    const [result] = await client.batchAnnotateImages(request);
   const detections = result.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation;
   console.log(detections.text);
 }
  quickstart().catch(console.error);
```

Here in the above code I have stored the image in GCS and used the path of that image in my code.

**Image :**

[image]

**Output :**

```
It was the best of
times, it was the worst
of times, it was the age
of wisdom, it was the
age of foolishness...
```

If you want to use the image file stored in the local system you can refer to the below code.

Since your file is in the [local system](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#detect_text_in_a_local_image), first you need to convert it to a [base64 encoded string](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/base64) format and pass the same in the [request parameters](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request#json_request_format) in your code.

**index.js :**

```
async function quickstart() {

   const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

   const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
  
   const request ={
     "requests":[
       {
         "image":{
           "content":"/9j/7QBEUGhvdG9...image contents...eYxxxzj/Coa6Bax//Z"
                },
         "features": [
           {
             "type":"TEXT_DETECTION"
           }
         ],
         "imageContext": {
           "languageHints": ["en"]
         }
       }
     ]
   };
   const [result] = await client.batchAnnotateImages(request);
   const detections = result.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation;
   console.log(detections.text);
  
   }
  
   quickstart();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! I don't know why this info was so difficult to find when I was searching for it, but I appreciate you writing this out for me!

Comment: @JToland Glad to help.